# Error al agregar referencias a mi proyecto Web

Tags: visual-studio

Buen día,

Tengo un proyecto en Visual Studio 2012 (Web Site hecho en visual basic), el cual, por actualización de las referencias (dll), se cambiaron.

La aplicacion web funcionaba bien, pero cuando se hizo el cambio de las dll, las referencias dejaron de funcionar. Aqui hago mención a que las nuevas referencias estan hechas a 64 bit y las anteriores estan hechas a 32.

El error que aparece es el siguiente:

> namespace or type specified in the imports <**nombre de la
>   referencia**> does not contain any public member.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, ¿Si es necesario hacer la compilacion a 64 bit?, ¿ Y cómo configuro mi ambiente para poderlo realizar?

Cualquier ayuda se los agradecre mucho.

Comment: en que carpeta estas ubicando estas dll ? si lo haces en el \bin\Debug o similar es incorrecto ubica una nueva carpeta a nivel del .sln, coloca alli las dll y ferencialas desde alli en el proyecto. Intentaste realizar un Rebuild de la solucion. Validaste que las dll tengan esta funcionalidad, si las usas desde otro proyecto diferente como ser uno winform de prueba puedes ver esta funcionalidad?

Comment: Gracias Leandro, si agrego las referencias a un Winform o incluso si creo un proyecto MVC si funcionan las nuevas DLL's, y si efectivamente la ruta de mis dll's estan en ..\Bin . Voy a cambiar la ruta y te hare saber mi resultado

Comment: Sigo con el mismo problema, cambie la carpeta donde tengo mis DLL's, hice un Rebuild, pero aún sigue sin reconocerlas.

Answer (score 1):

bueno como lo mencionas que se reemplazaron por actualización un error puede ser que el .Net Framework sean diferentes, esto en ocasiones puede provocar que no reconozca nada dentro de las .dll.

Si tienes acceso a el código de las .dll. 
Abre los proyectos desde visual, ve a propiedades y en aparecerá en un dropdownlist la versión de framework utilizada. Si son diferentes deberías asignarle a la utilizada por las .dll

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si se han modificado las DLL's se tiene que re-importar.

1. En el proyecto ve a *References*
2. Click Derecho y *Add Reference*
3. En la pantalla selecciona *Browse...*
4. Selecciona las nuevas DLLs (independientemente de dónde se encuentren)
5. Si sigue sin funcionar, ve a cualquier función que llame a las DLLs y pulsa **ALT+ENTER** y selecciona el *using*.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, este método fue lo que hice como primer instancia, pero como las dll's son de 64bits, no las reconoce.